# teradata: JSON_TABLE to shred array of numbers

Tags: json, teradata, teradatasql

On the Teradata database (ver.17), I would like to shred a JSON object as below:

```json
{
  "products": [{"category":"car", "name":"toyota"},
               {"category":"aircraft", "name":"boeing"},
               {"category":"fruit","name":"pear"}],
  "prices": [500, 100000, 1]
}
```

Here, `products` and `prices` arrays are paired; toyota's price is 500, boeing is 100000, and pear is 1.
My goal is to parse this into the following form:

```
id  category    name   price
----------------------------
 1       car  toyota     500
 1  aircraft  boeing  100000
 1     fruit    pear       1
```

My approach is to use [JSON_TABLE](https://docs.teradata.com/r/C8cVEJ54PO4%7EYXWXeXGvsA/sbSkXE4QHhd9Hj4rWhwi8w) to parse products and prices arrays separately and join afterwards.

I could shred the products part using `JSON_TABLE` function, but I got stuck for the prices part.

What I have so far is below:

```sql
/* create temp table for demo */
CREATE MULTISET VOLATILE TABLE test AS (
SELECT 1 AS id, NEW JSON('{
  "products":[{"category":"car","name":"toyota"},
              {"category":"aircraft","name":"boeing"},
              {"category":"fruit","name":"pear"}],
  "prices":[500,100000,1]}') AS doc
)
WITH DATA
ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS
;

/* working shredding for products part */
SELECT * FROM JSON_Table (
  ON (SELECT id, doc FROM test)
  USING rowexpr('$.products[*]')
        colexpr('[ {"jsonpath" : "$.category", "type" : "CHAR(20)"},
                   {"jsonpath" : "$.name", "type" : "VARCHAR(20)"},
                   {"ordinal" : true} ]')
) AS JT(id, category, name, ord)
;

/* failing for prices parts, just get NULLs */
SELECT * FROM JSON_Table (
  ON (SELECT id, doc FROM test)
  USING rowexpr('$.prices[*]')
        colexpr('[ {"jsonpath" : "$", "type" : "INTEGER"},
                   {"ordinal" : true} ]')
) AS JT(id, price, ord)
;
```

The results are below. The output from prices part is not something intended.

```
+----+------------------------------------------+--------+-----+
| id |                 category                 |  name  | ord |
+----+------------------------------------------+--------+-----+
| 1  | car                                      | toyota |  0  |
| 1  | aircraft                                 | boeing |  1  |
| 1  | fruit                                    |  pear  |  2  |
+----+------------------------------------------+--------+-----+


+----+-------+-----+
| id | price | ord |
+----+-------+-----+
| 1  |  None |  1  |
| 1  |  None |  1  |
| 1  |  None |  1  |
+----+-------+-----+
```

Can someone advise me on how I can shred the prices part of the JSON, preferably using `JSON_TABLE`?

Other approaches to achieve the same goal will also be appreciated.

I suppose `UNPIVOT` syntax could work, but I think it is not efficient because in reality I have much longer sequences and `UNPIVOT` requires I make a very wide table first (I could be wrong).  But if `UNPIVOT` is actually a good solution for my problem, please let me know that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if JSON_Table can be used to split a value array, but the result looks fishy: `ord` is always 1 instead of 0,1,2.

JSON_Shread works as expected:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TD_JSONSHRED(
ON
 (
   SELECT id, doc
   FROM test
 )
USING
   ROWEXPR('prices')
   COLEXPR('')
   RETURNTYPES('INTEGER')
) dt
;
```

But there's no ordinal returned.

This returns the expected result:

```
WITH cte AS 
 (
   SELECT id
     ,doc.prices[*] AS prices
   FROM test
 )
SELECT id, ord, trycast(token AS INTEGER) 
FROM TABLE
 ( STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE (cte.id, cte.prices, '[],')
   RETURNS (id integer, ord integer, token varchar(20)) 
 ) AS d
;
```

Comment: How is `STRTOK_SPLIT_TO_TABLE (cte.id, cte.prices, '[],')` working here?  Does it treat any of the characters in the third argument (`[],`) as a delimiter?

Comment: @Andrew: Exactly, any number of those characters. If there's a multi-character delimiter or if you want to treat two consecutive delimiters as empty/null switch to REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE.